# What do the letters 'sdf' in the old favicon stand for?

Tags: discussion, favicon

**Update**: the favicon is now 'XLM', the currency symbol for Lumens:

[image]

---

What do the letters 'sdf' in the old favicon

[image]

stand for?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The letters 'sdf' stand for [Stellar Development Foundation](https://www.stellar.org/about/mandate/), the organization which maintains the Stellar network. Why they are in lowercase can probably only be answered by the Community Managers (employees of [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/company), who maintain this site).

'Stellar' itself would be too long to fit; the risk of using just 's' is duplicating another (possibly future) site in the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: Preferring lower case to upper is a bit of an SE convention that goes way back. Text and prompts throughout the site tend to be all lower case always, unless someone specifies that it needs to be in upper case specifically (think `IBM`). The convention isn't being followed as much as it used to be, but favicons and site icons tend to be more symbolic than literal, so when I picked the favicon for this site, I was in a lower-case mood... and I went with that.

Comment: so XLM is not an option? :(

Comment: @Crosscounter `XLM` *is* more consistent with preferring official codes for countries/languages/currencies when they are available. The actual favicon is largely inconsequential, but let me see how hard/easy that is to change after the fact.

Comment: Why not use the rocket Stellar logo?

Comment: @AndreiSavin:  Using the Stellar logo may be an option if this site graduates from beta.  Provided SE gets permission to use it.  Beta sites don't get artwork of that nature.